# how to convert the output of a PHP into a string to be used in Android?

Tags: php, android, json, url, encode

I have a .php file on the server side that works fine and extracts me results with PDO method. Therefore, when I click the file on the browser, I have no problem.

Yet, I would like this output to be put in a textView in my Android app.

Now, by the end of the php file i added:

```
print(json_encode(array($output)));
```

while in MainActivity.class I tried to get this output by parsing it through JSON.

```
try {
        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        }

        TextView.setText(s);
```

Now, how do I end the JSONObject, so that "s" becomes a String that can later be added to the TextView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your JSONObject contain ?

Comment: If you want to show the JSON content into a TextView, you can convert your JSONArray to a String and show this String by use TextView.setText(jArray.toString());

Comment: Try to display the value of the 'result' variable to the logCat and share it with us please.

Comment: @DeveloperX Hi, my JSONObject is something silly I took from the internet
http://pastebin.com/NtkMGuBw

Comment: @Bubu therefore something like this, correct? http://pastebin.com/9CkwKKu9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
String s=""; 
JSONArray jArray = result.getJSONArray(result); 
for(int i=0 ; i < jArray.length() ; i++) {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    s = s+"Price : "+json.getString("Price");
}
TextView.setText(s);
```

Comment: Hi Naveed, I get a few errors: (1) what are "result" and ""response" in the first row? by "title" you mean one of the Fields in the output, correct? I get a further error in "json.getString(i)"; what is exactly "i"?

Thanks in advance